# Unable to run a shell commmand programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, shortcut

I'm trying to create a shortcut to call a shell command. If I run the command in PowerShell it works, but in code it doesn't. Why?

```
Start-Process shell:$("AppsFolder\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt!App")
```

In code would be:

```
 public static void CreateLink()
 {
     IShellLinkW link = (IShellLinkW)new ShellLink();

     // setup shortcut information
     link.SetDescription("My Description");
     link.SetPath(@"%Windir%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe");
     link.SetArguments(@"Start-Process shell:$(""AppsFolder\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt!App"")");

     // save it
     IPersistFile file = (IPersistFile)link;
     string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
     file.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "MyLink.lnk"), false);
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: After pressing the created shortcut I get the following error in PowerShell : AppsFolder\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt!App : The module 'AppsFolder' could not be loaded. 

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.  !!!!But run it in the PowerShell by hand and it will work.

Comment: You shouldn't have to start up a PowerShell to run "shell:X" from a link. Since "shell:X" works directly in the run box (Win+R) it should also work directly in a link. Try `link.SetPath("shell:AppsFolder\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt!App")` and remove `link.SetArguments()`.

Comment: You're the best.